# Search with ShowfindDialog in webview not highlighting

Tags: android, search, android-webview, highlighting

For Android 3.x I used :

```
webview.showFindDialog(string_to_find, true);
```

It's working well.

However, for Android 4.x it finds the number of occurences but doesn't highlight them...

Any workaround ?

Thanks !

Comment: In fact, it works well for android 4.0 but not for android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4...

Comment: Reproduced the no-highlight behaviour on my Galaxy Nexus running stock 4.0.4. Also the search text itself is a rather illegible black-on-blue, probably due to me using a 'dark' theme on my actionbar.

Comment: You might be interested in the fact that [this method is now deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in API 18.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known bug in ICS. It's been reported here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29987 I've seen a possible workaround elsewhere (calling a private method setFindIsUp) but it hasn't worked for me.. =/

Comment: I'm the person who reported the bug ^^
Tried the setFindIsUp method but didn't worked for me neither...